# Rhomobile running issue on Android device

Tags: rhomobile

Hi i am using rhomobile for making a hybrid app. When i run this app on emulator it runs fine. but when i try to run it on android device after plugging in usb cable. it shows following output on console.

build started

```
PWD: C:\Users\priyanka2\workspace\DemoApp
CMD: rake run:android:device
cd C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-4.0.0
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - wmic OS get OSArchitecture

Tasks: TOP => run:android:device => device:android:debug =>  package:android =>
              build:android:all => build:android:rhobundle => config:android
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
1.9.3
$app_config['extensions'] : ["coreapi", "json", "rhoconnect-client"]
$app_config['capabilities'] : []
Using Android SDK build-tools: android-4.3
$vendor = rhomobile`enter code here`
$app_package_name = com.rhomobile.demoapp
RET: 1
Error in build application. Build is terminated.
```

Comment: Any luck getting this solved? ?

Comment: At my computer this file is in C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe. It's a part of WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation). For solving issues in it, Microsoft has The WMI Diagnosis Utility: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7684

Comment: "No such file or directory" error suggests that maybe registering WMI again could fix that: http://windowsxp.mvps.org/repairwmi.htm

Comment: any solution for this?